# MongoDB $match and $group problems

Tags: mongodb

i trying to get a match count out becures i have a kind of problems so i will change my `find().count()` to `aggregate()` methode.

My problem is when i add my $match its not return nothing in count, if i remove the line its works fine.

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate(
   [
      { $match: { 'Store.Title': { $regex: '/apc/', $options: 'gi' } } },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

can somebody help me and explain what i do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** object to create the regex object first then use it in your pipeline:

```
var apc_match = new RegExp('apc', 'gi');

db.getCollection('product').aggregate(
   [
      { $match: { 'Store.Title': apc_match } },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
);
```

OR

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate(
   [
      { $match: { 'Store.Title': { $regex: 'apc', $options: 'gi' } } },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
);
```

OR

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate(
   [
      { $match: { 'Store.Title': /apc/gi } },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
);
```

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser No worries, happy to help :-)